# What is new between APS and APS Connect

Tags: php, aps

In Odin Automation 7 (Premium). There is a concept of APS connect framework. Being an APS 2.0 developer I would like to know what is new in APS connect framework.

What exactly is this framework about? And what are the new thing we have to learn from APS developer point of view. I am asking these questions here because there is no documentation available about APS Connect over internet.

Answer (score 0):

APS Connect does not replace APS 2.0 framework - it is a Self-Onboarding IDE tool that autogenerates the package template for new APS packages. This streamlines the on-boarding process and reduces TTM and the learning curve required to join the APS ecosystem. The tool also offers a standardized operations environment, automated testing, auto-deployment/lifecycle management features. Future releases will include service provider discovery, simplified certification/assessment processes and more.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article dedicated to this topic in the APS Connect FAQ: https://help.aps.odin.com/faq/aps-connect-vs-standard.

The short and simple answer is: **APS Connect is a framework** that still uses **APS Standard technology** under the hood. APS Connect was created to reduce services integration costs, while maintaining 100% compatibility with APS Standard.

Please follow the aforereferenced article for more details.
You might also want to watch this video tutorial that covers the same topic: https://youtu.be/2OtnajHg5Zc